# How to filter layer by attribute custom magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How do i coding ???
 When i new layer filter by attribute desginer, and i set url custom by `.../catalog/category/designer/name/123`

I have 4 product show list, but when i click layer select size L (2)
        I recive 4 products ( i want its show 2 product filter size L )
        Who can help me ??
        This is my code

```
public function designerAction()
        {
        $designer = $this -> getRequest() -> getParam('name');
         $data_designer=array();                   
                        $attributes = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')->getCollection()->setStoreFilter()->join('attribute','attribute.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id', 'attribute_code');
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {             
                    if ($attribute->getOptionId()==$designer) {                  
                        $data_designer['name']=$attribute->getValue();
                        $data_designer['desc']=$attribute->getDescription();
                        $data_designer['image']=$attribute->getImage();                   
                    }
                }  
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                     ->addFilter('type_id', 'configurable')                       
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('designer', $designer)  ;

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

        $this->loadLayout();

        $listBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
                ->setTemplate('catalog/product/designer.phtml')

                ->setCollection($collection);
        $listBlock->setData('data',  $data_designer);
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($listBlock);

        $this->renderLayout();
        }
```

Comment: question is unclear...how many product is return in $collection

Answer (score 0):

no, my collection return left Layer when i using attribute URL, when i using left layer with attribue color or size, url will set ...../?color=3&size=2

But my collection can't get url attribute ==> my list product not effect with attribute